# What does ctrl-opt-v do in OS X?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, text-editing

If you edit text on a Mac and press `ctrl-opt-v`, nothing *appears* to happen. But if you now use the arrow keys to move the cursor, you will notice that it will "stand still" at the point where you pressed the keys. It's as if the cursor is stepping over an invisible, zero-width character. I have verified the behavior in many, but not all, applications.

What is the purpose of this?

Comment: Cannot reproduce the described behavior on 10.9.2 in TextEdit. Could you please be more specific as to when it happens?

Comment: I also can not reproduce this behaviour. Have you checked in `System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts` if maybe this shortcut is attached to a custom service?

Comment: I have figured out as much as this: it inserts a [synchronous idle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronous_idle) character, but the purpose of this is still very unclear. I'm on 10.8.4. The strange behavior is more obvious if you have pressed the keys several times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more experimentation and research, I'm answering my own question:

It appears that `ctrl-opt-[letter]` inserts one of the ASCII control codes, which do not display as visible characters. `Ctrl-opt-v` inserts the `SYN` *synchronous idle* control code, but other letters will produce similar behavior. [This page lists the keys](http://academic.evergreen.edu/projects/biophysics/technotes/program/ascii_ctrl.htm) and their corresponding control codes, and Wikipedia has [more info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character#How_control_characters_map_to_keyboards) as well.

I have inserted the synchronous idle character 10 times in the following parenthesis: **()**. <s>Although it is not likely to produce anything on your screen, you might be able to copy this text into a text editor, and observe the behavior as the cursor tries to step through the parenthesis.</s> *Unfortunately it appears that the server strips out the control codes before rendering the page.*